# How to calculate distance by counting pixels

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing

My goal is to identify two LEDs, one dynamic and the other static and calculate the distance and speed between them.
Using openCV I thought to identify the LEDs and the number of pixels between them to calculate the distance. Is it possible? And if so how do you do it.

Thanks,
T. Krispin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the real distance between objects in a 2D image, you need more than detecting the objects and calculate the number of pixels between them. There are a lot of parameters that you need to concern about, e.g the distance from camera to the objects, the camera's resolution, the angle of the camera, the angle of the objects ...

I recommend you to take a look at below posts to have more insight about this matter.

1. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/19/find-distance-camera-objectmarker-using-python-opencv/
2. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/04/measuring-distance-between-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/

Ps. I'm not from PyImageSearch, I'm just a fan of this wonderful blog.